# how to call win32 dll from .NET application folder

Tags: c#, winapi, dllimport

i can call (DLLImport) Win32 .DLL file from a constant specified path in C#.NET.
but if i want to load it from my aplications folder (executavle file path) , what shoud i do?
the DLLImport Attribute doesn't allow to specify a variable path.
plz help me. tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just specify dll name without path. As below:

```
    [DllImport("Dllname.dll")]
    static extern void Foo();
```

And it would be searched in app folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you DLLImport without specifying any path it should look in the application folder.

Answer (score 1):

Use SetDllDirectory Function to specify a path of your choice.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)] 
static extern bool SetDllDirectory(string lpPathName);
```

More on MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686203%28VS.85%29.aspx

Check earlier post on stackoverflow: 
[Specify the search path for DllImport in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864673/specify-the-search-path-for-dllimport-in-net)