# DllNotFound Exception when I use glut functions in my Dll

Tags: c#, c++, dll, glut, dllnotfoundexception

I have a c++ dll and c# application. In C# application I call function from dll.
With simple function like:

```
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) void HelloFromDll()
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("Hello from DLL"), _T("Hello from DLL"), NULL);
    }
}
```

all works fine.
When i use function with glut like this:

```
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) int InitGlut()
    {
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
        glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
        glutInitWindowSize(320,320);
        glutCreateWindow("MyWindow");
        glutDisplayFunc(renderScene);
        glutMainLoop();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

i get DllNotFound Exception. Why?
C# code:

```
const string pathToDll = "../../../Release/MyDLL.dll";
[DllImport(pathToDll)]
public static extern void HelloFromDll();
[DllImport(pathToDll)]
public static extern int InitGlut();

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    HelloFromDll();
    InitGlut();
}
```

Comment: please verify an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your [working directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory.aspx) of your application to the path of the DLL's, this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
 const string pathToDll = "../../../Release/MyDLL.dll";
```

Odds are not great that this would be a valid path.  Or that it helps Windows find any dependent DLLs, it doesn't.  What's much worse is that the odds are zero after you deployed your app.

Add a post build event to your project that copies all the required native DLLs into the $(TargetDir) directory with xcopy /d /y.  Windows always looks there first.  And it will work both when you debug and after you deploy.  And your build directory contains everything you need to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

[Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864673/specify-the-search-path-for-dllimport-in-net).
The name of the DLL and the path need to be split as shown there...