# What Azure services to choose?

Tags: azure

I use a third party DLL loaded to c:\Windows\System32\ in my local ASP.NET project. What kind of Microsoft Azure service I have to apply to migrate and run the web application in cloud?

Comment: Why does it have to be located in the system folder?

Comment: Because I load it on OS startup. This library written in pure C and I refer to it's functions in unsafe mode. I'm not sure if it compatible  with ASP.NET references. If you now how to connect С DLL to project please advice.

Comment: So you use P/Invoke, don't you? Then it's not necessary to put the library to the system folder http://stackoverflow.com/a/2864714/57428

Comment: That's P/Invoke. The linked to answer explains that you can tune it so that it can load the library from anywhere.

Comment: But what should I do on the cloud side? I know the library path on my local mashine, but don't know after uploading to the cloud as website (not VM). I have to drop dll folder to ASP.NET project root before uploading?

Comment: You have to include it into the project and figure out how to locate it relative to the project root. For example, you can use `RdRoleRoot` environment variable in case of web role.

Comment: Am I do right? ```String rootPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RoleRoot");``` ```SetDllDirectory(rootPath + @"\myFolderWithDll");```

Comment: Well, does it work? I guess not because your role contents ends up in `approot` subfolder.

Comment: Actually no. Look, I didn't get necessary path information here: http://trydll2.azurewebsites.net/Home/About

Comment: Then what did you get?

Comment: Nothing. String vars are empty or null when I expect root path.

Comment: Does `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RdRoleRoot")` return an empty string on Azure?

Comment: Yeah, as I can see on the site that result of ```string roleRootDir = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RdRoleRoot");``` is just ```roleRootDir =```, so empty output.

Comment: The link you provided leads to "Azure website", not a web role. I have no idea if you can run unmanaged code in website. Anyway you could try listing all environment variables and perhaps find one which gives you the application root.

Comment: That's works: ```string roleRootDir = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME");
            var home = Path.Combine(roleRootDir, @"site\wwwroot\");```

Comment: Thank you, sharptooth for direct me! :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to manually install this DLL in the above mentioned directory, best way to host your application would be in `Azure Virtual Machines (IaaS)`. There you get full control of the VM and can install anything you like.

Comment: Could he use a web role and install the library using an elevated startup task?

Comment: He possibly could but there's an overhead of converting the application to run as web role (because of web role's stateless nature). IMHO the least painful migration path would be Virtual Machines.