# Managing tons of 3rdparty dependencies in PInvoke for better compilation speed

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, dependency-management

**The situation:**

I'm working on a research project which, due to some constraints, has a C# user interface (used mostly for visualization) but does most of the processing with PInvoke and unmanaged C++ code. The unmanaged code has TONS of dependencies on various 3rdparty libraries: Boost, PCL, OpenCV, CGAL, VTK, Eigen, FLANN, OpenMesh, etc. (if you can name it, we probably depend on it!). The C# project interacts with a C++ project (which I simply refer to as "wrapper" from now on). Obviously, the wrapper is where all the 3rdparty dependencies are consumed and is where entry points for PInvokes are defined. The wrapper is compiled into a DLL and copied into the output directory of the C# project via a post-build event.

I am the sole developer of the project. My primary development platform is Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2015 and Git is my version control. I mostly develop on 3 differenct machines, but sometimes I need to develop on other machines which only have Visual Studio 2015 installed.

**What I've done so far:**

Obsiously, managing all those 3rdparty dependencies is a hassle for one person, and I'd hate to have to install those libraries on new development machines . What I've done is that I've compiled all those 3rdparty libraries from source into static lib files (except the header-only ones obviously). All sources are built once for `Debug` configuration and once for `Release` configuration. I spent some time and integrated them into my wrapper project (i.e. defining extra include directories, using lots of `#pragma comment (lib, "blah.lib")` which reference different builds depending on the build configuration, etc.). I also followed some of the advice in [Microsoft's linker best practices](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2013/10/29/the-visual-c-linker-best-practices-developer-iteration/), to reduce link times. Specifically, I'm using the incremental linker, I've disabled `/LTCG` and `/OPT`.

Now I have this gigantic "Dependencies" folder in my VS solution which is around 8GBs, and is version-controlled separately from the project (using a Git submodule). The wrapper project gets statically linked to all these, as a result and as mentioned above, only one DLL is produced after building the wrapper project. The upside of this approach is that on any new development machine, I clone the main repository, clone the Dependencies submodule and I'm ready to roll! But...

**The worst part:**

You've guessed it! Terrible link times. Even on a powerful computer, after I change a single line in the wrapper project, I would have to sit for a couple of minutes till the linker finishes. The thing I didn't see when I took the above approach was that I forgot how much I valued rapid prototyping: quick and dirty testing of some random feature in the wrapper project before exposing that feature to PInvoke. Ideally, I would like to be able to change something small in the wrapper project, quickly build, run and test that change and get on with exposing the feature to PInvoke.

**My Question:**

Clearly, I'm inexperienced in this! How should I have done things differently, specifically given the dependencies I mentioned above? Was building DLLs instead of static libraries better? But then I would've had to add the Dependencies to PATH everytime the C# program started ([as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864673/specify-the-search-path-for-dllimport-in-net)). As a side question, how do you evaluate my current approach?

Comment: Do you actually need all those dependencies in a single executable? Could it be possible to separate your app into different 'services'?

That way, the UI can access a different executable depending on the task, or if the tasks are related, they could communicate via IPC. You could then have multiple smaller executables with fewer dependencies.

Comment: @silverscania I do and I can't break the executable up unfortunately... The thing is, the executable is shared with another group regularly, and they use it for a part of their system... It's easier to ship something to them that works out of the box...

Comment: Then I think if your problem is purely with link times then DLLs are the way to go. You don't have to change the PATH as long as they are in the same directory or a subdirectory of your application.

Comment: @silverscania Thanks a lot! I posted an answer based on your comment. I'm super happy now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment by @silverscania, I decided to just take the DLL route. It was a bit of pain rebuilding all the dependencies, but I'm now super happy about the results.

Now, building the whole solution from scratch takes 36 seconds! It used to be about 4 minutes before, so I have nothing to complain about. Also, modifying a single file in the wrapper project and building again takes 3 seconds which is amazing! The fact that all the compiled dependencies are now about 1 GB (opposed to ~8GB with the static libraries) is a plus! I couldn't be happier.

**A coupt of notes:**

1. On the main machine where I do most of my development, I have a SanDisk SSD. I noticed that for some reason beyond my comprehension, building the project on that device was **way** slower compared to a regular HDD. I'm looking into this issue, but haven't found an reason for this (TRIM is enabled and the drive is in AHCI mode).
2. I played around with the flags a bit more. I noticed that the compiler flag `/GL` (Whole program optimization) caused considerable slowdown during linking. I disabled that option too.