# VB.Net DllImport Set Location

Tags: vb.net, dllimport

I am having an issue on deploying only. When I run program in Visual Studios everything works fine. When I deploy to the server, the program errors out. I have the E_BEPSET32.DLL within the folder where my .exe is however it fails find the E_BEPSET32.DLL.

Is there a way that you can specify the file path and DLL. If I hard code the file path and file name it works fine but I would rather not do that. I see that it can be done in C# but i am not sure how to convert this to VB

[Specify the search path for DllImport in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864673/specify-the-search-path-for-dllimport-in-net)

```
<DllImport("E_BEPSET32.DLL", EntryPoint:="EPDM_Open")>
    Public Shared Function EPDM_Open(DrvName As String, PortName As String, Type As Integer, DMAdd As IntPtr, ByRef PrnHandleAdd As IntPtr) As Integer
    End Function
```

Comment: You probably forgot to copy the DLLs that this one needs, typically the C and/or C++ runtime DLLs.   Run Dumpbin.exe /imports to see their names.  Running the Epson installer on the target machine is best.

Comment: Well, If i hard code the path to the DLL it works just fine

Comment: Well, you already know that this doesn't make sense from your previous question about it.  So that's not the problem.