# Load native library from application's runtimes directory in .NET 5 application

Tags: c#, .net-core, dll

I have .NET 5 application native dependencies distributed in `runtimes` directory as follows:

```
runtimes/
├── win-x64/
│   └── native/
│       └── plugin.dll
├── win-x86/
│   └── native/
│       └── plugin.dll
├── linux-x64/
│   └── native/
│       └── plugin.so
⋮
└── app.exe
```

From the application `app.exe` I need to load the native `plugin.dll`/`so` at runtime (using the `NativeLibrary.Load` method). Now I need to build candidate paths to look for the right native library based on the runtime identifier. I can get application's current RID from `System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.RuntimeIdentifier`. However it returns e.g. `win7-x64` but the native library is located in `win-x64`. In ideal case I would need to enumerate all [compatible RIDs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog#rid-graph) and try to load the library from each of them from the most specific to the least until I find the library. Is there such mechanism available as public API? I know this works with P/Invoke however I need to do this dynamically at runtime. I don't want to parse `runtime.json` or `.deps.json`. Any better idea?

Comment: It think you solve issue with installation package and not at runtime.  The installation package should recognize the type of machine and then install the correct dll's.

Answer (score 2):

So one must use the high-level API method `NativeLibrary.Load(string libraryName, Assembly assembly, DllImportSearchPath? searchPath)` which already handles the variations in runtime paths. The low-level method `NativeLibrary.Load(string libraryPath)` does not.

Comment: This answer helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45384763/1121437 in terms of the searchPath parameter.